# XSLT whitespace elements getting trimmed

Tags: xslt, whitespace

Quick question. I have some XML

```
<someXML>
  <someNode>     </someNode>
  <someNode>asdlkjf    </someNode>
</someXML>
```

When i apply an XSLT to this the first node is getting trimmed into nothing. The second is fine and the trailing whitespace is not trimmed because i'm preserving whitespace:

```
<someXML>
  <someNode></someNode>
  <someNode>asdlkjf    </someNode>
</someXML>
```

My question is why is the first node getting truncated? As absurd as this sounds, the whitespace node is important and needs to be maintained. I'm using Xalan 2.7.1. Is this just the way XSL works or is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this XSLT directive**:

```
 <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
```

If this doesn't help, this means that the XML parser is stripping the whitespace-only text nodes.

To prevent this, in the XML document use the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute:

```
<someXML>
    <someNode xml:space="preserve">     </someNode>
    <someNode>asdlkjf    </someNode>
</someXML>
```